# LocalStorage returning null in a different tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my issue:

I update the localStorage in popup.js in a new tab. I access the same localStorage(same key) in the background.js.

Now this is returning null in every tab apart from the chrome://extensions tab(when I load the extensions.)

I thought localStorage was persistant across all tabs.

Code:

popup.js:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    alert(localStorage.getItem('filters'));
    var oldFilters = localStorage.getItem('filters');
    //All the filters show up on the popup.html page.
    document.getElementById('td1').innerHTML = oldFilters;

    var dat = oldFilters + "," + newArray[j]
    localStorage.setItem('filters',String(dat));
}
```

background.js:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

 var filters = localStorage.getItem('filters');

   alert("background + "+ filters);
    //This shows all the filters in the chrome:extensions page but always pops up "background + null" in every new tab load. 

//changeImage(filters);

});
```

Comment: If you view your local storage in inspect element->resources is anything there?

Comment: Nope. There is nothing there.

Comment: Are you certain it is ever being set?

Comment: Absolutely, this is the flow. That's why it shows me all the stored data when I go to chrome:extensions page and reload the data.

Comment: And I don't think so that I would have set the data in background.js everytime I open a new tab, now do I?

Comment: It definitely should be persisting across multiple tabs. Can you maybe post a bit of code?

Comment: Have added the code of popup.js and background.js

Comment: Where in popup.js does it update localStorage?

Comment: Had forgotten to add that piece of code that does that. Have changed the popup.js to show that.

Comment: It looks like your `background.js` is in fact used as content script. You wrote in the comment that it "shows all the filters in the chrome:extensions page but always pops up "background + null" in **every new tab load**." Background page does not reload itself into each tab.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) and [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)(In your case) Pages live in isolated worlds, their local storage details are not accessible to each other, if you want this sort of access to happen use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) for your storage needs.

It has few advantages

- *Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.*
- *A user's extension settings can be persisted even when using split incognito behavior.*
- *User data can be stored as objects (the localStorage API stores data in strings).*

#### Methods used

- [`chrome.storage.local.get`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get)
- [`chrome.storage.local.set`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-set)
  (use `sync` instead of `local` if the data needs to be synchronized with Google Sync)

#### Demonstration

#### manifest.json

Ensure all permissions are available for accessing storage API.

```
{
"name":"Local Storage Demo",
"description":"This is a small use case for using local storage",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
"browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"popup.html",
    "default_icon":"logo.png"
},
"permissions":["storage"]
}
```

#### popup.html

A trivial popup html page which refers popup.js to surpass CSP.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

#### background.js

This scripts sets content to chrome storage

```
//Set some content from background page
chrome.storage.local.set({"identifier":"Some awesome Content"},function (){
    console.log("Storage Succesful");
});
//get all contents of chrome storage
chrome.storage.local.get(null,function (obj){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

#### popup.js

This script retrieves and sets content from\to chrome storage

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function (){
    //Fetch all contents
    chrome.storage.local.get(null,function (obj){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    });
    //Set some content from browser action
    chrome.storage.local.set({"anotherIdentifier":"Another awesome Content"},function (){
        console.log("Storage Succesful");
    });
});
```

If you look at outputs of these js pages, communication of storage **(Background -> popup and popup -> background)** is achieved.

Comment: Brilliant answer.  I tried many solutions on SO and this one made me again believe in the beauty humanity!  Thanks