# chrome not letting me use sessions methods?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session

I am trying to display recent tabs in a extension that I am expanding on.

When I try to run this code;

```
chrome.sessions.getDevices(function(data) { console.log(data);});
```

I get this error;

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDevices' of undefined
```

I have given my manifest.json "sessions" permissions and cannot figure out why it gives me this. Do I have to clear my chrome cache to reload permissions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113562/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-local-of-undefined-in-chrome-extensio

Comment: hi, i have already looked over this question and i have already added permissions, checked my google chrome build, and i am writing my script in the right context and I still produce this error

Comment: @KyleCasey did you find the solution

Comment: @ManiKandanSelvanathan its been a long while, but I remember needing local cache permissions or something like that, and I had to completely remove and add my plugin to chrome so chrome would prompt me to give my plugin the right permissions