# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined error despite having storage permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api

Unlike in a similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113562/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-local-of-undefined-in-chrome-extensio) post where adding "storage" as permission resolved the issue, I get the error despite having storage permission.  I get the error not in chrome://extension but when I open a live server & check the console

Background.js:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({event: 'test'}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + 'test');
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['event'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "To be named",
    "description": "This extension helps...",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "identity",
        "identity.email",
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test",
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/Time"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },  
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/"], 
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "css": ["styles.css"]
    }]
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined in content.js but not background in the console.
```

Comment: Sounds like you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: I actually did multiple times

Comment: Then you didn't reload the tab with youtube. There are no other explanations... BTW the list of errors on chrome://extensions page contains all old errors, not just the current ones.

Comment: I actually opened a live server from the popup.html & saw the error in the console along with the rest of the html. I've done command + shift + R multiples times too. I know that's why I'm so confused :(

Comment: You're doing something weird there. Extension pages can't be opened from a live server (from a http or file URL), they should be opened properly so that they have chrome-extension:// URL.

Comment: so how should they be opened? cause that was my way of debugging & visualizing the front end aka content.js. Update: when I changed `"https://www.youtube.com/"` to `"<all_urls>" ` & reloaded http://127.0.0.1:5500/popup.html, console finally did get printed even though the error persists which I assume I shall avoid?

Comment: Like I said, extension pages should be opened properly so they have chrome-extension:// URL. Your manifest.json doesn't contain any extension pages so I can only guess it's a `browser_action` popup which should be opened by clicking the icon of the extension in the toolbar or the puzzle icon menu.