# Modify local storage via popup, and use stored values in contentscript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, local-storage, browser-action

I'm trying my hand at creating a chrome extension, but am running into a wall.

I want to be able to use the browser-action popup to write/modify values into local storage (extension storage).

Then, I want to use the stored values in a content script.

From what I've read, it looks like I need a background file? but I'm not sure.

Some coded examples would be extremely appreciated!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you use [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) instead, you won't have this problem. See [window.localStorage vs chrome.storage.local](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279495/window-localstorage-vs-chrome-storage-local/24281357#24281357)

Comment: @Xan This looks like what I want! What's the deal with the callback function on the get and sets though? I've never encountered something like this, and the documentation is a bit ominous. I think I have it done correctly on the set, but do I do something special for the get? Thanks again!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688171/after-calling-chrome-tabs-query-the-results-are-not-available/11689804#11689804) by Rob W, though dealing with another API function, explains the pitfalls of callbacks very nicely. You just have to wrap your head around it once.

Comment: @Xan I've got it reading and writing now. Didn't click that I had to write my code within the callback. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Xan Will you please restate your comments as an answer, so that I can mark this question as closed? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid using a background page as a proxy if you use [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). It's a storage solution that is available from Content Scripts directly.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279495/window-localstorage-vs-chrome-storage-local/24281357#24281357) is a comparison between it and `localStorage` in the context of Chrome extensions.

---

An important thing to note is that it's asynchronous, making code slightly more complicated than using `localStorage`:

```js
/* ... */
chrome.storage.local.get('key', function(value){
  // You can use value here
});
// But not here, as it will execute before the callback
/* ... */
```

But to be fair, if you go with the background being the proxy for data, message passing is still asynchronous.

---

One can argue that once the data is passed, `localStorage` works as a synchronous cache.

But that `localStorage` object is shared with the web page, which is insecure, and nobody stops you from having your own synchronous storage cache, initialized once with `chrome.storage.local.get(null, /*...*/)` and kept up to date with a `chrome.storage.onChanged` listener.

Answer (score 1):

Background pages can access the localStorage variables saved by your extension. Your content script only has access to the localStorage of the website open in a specific tab. You will therefore need to send the variables from the background page to the content script. The content script can then access these variables.

The following code saves a localStorage variable in the background script and then sends it to the content script for use.

Since you requested a coded example, I've written you one. This project would have a background page and a content script. Using localStorage in your popup will allow the background page to access these variables for use in the content script.

Something like this:

**background.js**

```
// When a tab is updated
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {

    // When the tab has loaded
    if(changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

        // Query open tabs
        chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {

            // Get URL of current tab
            var tabURL = tabs[0].url;

            // If localStorage is not empty
            if(localStorage.length != 0) {

                // Set a local storage variable
                localStorage.helloworld = "Hello World";

                // Send message to content script
                chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

                    // Send request to show the notification
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {

                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**contentscript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    // Use the local storage variable in some way
    if(request.greeting == "hello") {

        var hello = localStorage.helloworld;

        // do something with the variable here
    }
});
```

Once you have this working, consider switching to [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)