# Option issue using chrome.storage.sync.get for first time user

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('savedItem', function (result) {

    //some if else condition for result.savedItem here
    myResult = result.savedItem;
    });

$('p').val(myResult);
```

With above code, I got an undefined, **because there is no setting been saved in my options page for the first time user**. I tried to set a default value to myResult like `if(result.savedItem == undefined) myResult = '';` but I still got undefined. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2 issues at the same time.

1) You can set default for values not in the storage by providing a dictionary:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({'savedItem' : 'myDefault'}, function (result) {
  // result.savedItem is the saved value or 'myDefault'
});
```

2) The biggest issue is not understanding how asynchronous code works.

`$('p').val(myResult);` gets executed before `myResult` is assigned, because `chrome.storage.sync.get` returns immediately, with the `function(result){...}` being called later.

There have been *tons* of questions about that, take a look at, say, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25626398/934239) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

Comment: any idea bout this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899388/google-custom-font-in-chrome-extension-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

Use chrome storage change - [Refer this link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#type-StorageChange)

Example code:

```
    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
        for (var key in changes) {
            var storageChange = changes[key];
            console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. ' + 'Old value was "%s", new value is "%s".', key, namespace, storageChange.oldValue, storageChange.newValue);
        }
    });
```