# How can I remain on same page window on Chrome browser extension when it closes?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, browser-extension

I'm developing a Chrome browser extension that that has different menu links that go to different pages in the extension.  I noticed each time the extension closes I have to navigate back to the last page I was on in the extension.

Is there a way to keep the last page I'm on current even if the extension window closes?

Comment: By "extension" you mean "browser action popup", right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I instruct Chrome Extension to NOT reload my HTML each time it is opened?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398014/how-can-i-instruct-chrome-extension-to-not-reload-my-html-each-time-it-is-opened)

Comment: @Xan yes, thank you...i think this is what i'm looking for.  i saw your comment on this link; i guess this does get asked a lot...haha. :)

Comment: This - no, but the Overview page is a vital resource to understanding how extensions are structured.