# Storage Quota for Chrome.Storage.Sync?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension is going to be saving data like this in a string using `Chrome.Storage.Sync.Set`, which I will then interpret with regex/something similar:

```
<ID>TEXTBOX</ID><STYLE>BORDER:1PX SOLID BLACK; BACKGROUND-COLOR:YELLOW;
FONT-SIZE:18PX; FONT-FAMILY:ARIAL</STYLE><OTHER></OTHER>
```

I'm hoping to put all saved data in one storage item. ie:

```
<ID>TEXTBOX</ID><STYLE>BORDER:1PX SOLID BLACK; BACKGROUND-COLOR:YELLOW;
FONT-SIZE:18PX; FONT-FAMILY:ARIAL</STYLE><OTHER></OTHER>
<ID>TEXTBOX</ID><STYLE>BORDER:1PX SOLID BLACK; BACKGROUND-COLOR:YELLOW;
FONT-SIZE:18PX; FONT-FAMILY:ARIAL</STYLE><OTHER></OTHER>
<ID>TEXTBOX</ID><STYLE>BORDER:1PX SOLID BLACK; BACKGROUND-COLOR:YELLOW;
FONT-SIZE:18PX; FONT-FAMILY:ARIAL</STYLE><OTHER></OTHER>
<ID>TEXTBOX</ID><STYLE>BORDER:1PX SOLID BLACK; BACKGROUND-COLOR:YELLOW;
FONT-SIZE:18PX; FONT-FAMILY:ARIAL</STYLE><OTHER></OTHER>
```

This page [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea) says for each "individual item in sync storage, as measured by the JSON stringification of its value plus its key length.", the size limit is 8,192 bytes. **From anyone's knowledge, am I likely to go over the limit? Say if I had 40 IDs..**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. Yes, you are likely to go over the [limit](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea). Your current example, with 4 IDs, is approximately half a kilobyte. So you'll run out with 64 already.

Then your `set` operation will fail, and in your callback `chrome.runtime.lastError` will be set:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set(data, function() {
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    // Uh-oh..
  }
});
```

Do note:

- If you don't really need to sync all this data across devices, use `chrome.storage.local`. It has a much more generous quota of 5,242,880 bytes..
- ..which is removed if you ask for `"unlimitedStorage"` permission.
- As Google documentation puts it, in a somewhat tongue-in-cheek fashion:

  > `chrome.storage` is not a big truck. It's a series of tubes. And if you don't understand, those tubes can be filled, and if they are filled when you put your message in, it gets in line, and it's going to be delayed by anyone that puts into that tube enormous amounts of material.

  Sync storage requires support from Google's infrastructure - and they are not willing to give it out for free in unlimited amounts.
- It's quite ineffective to put all this data in the storage. Analyze it, and store the analysis results - you get a cleaner data in storage.

P.S. [HTML is not a regular language.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/934239)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I'll mark it complete just one more Q - would you suggest using Chrome.Storage.Local or HTML5 Local Storage?

Comment: [window.localStorage vs chrome.storage.local](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24279495/934239)

Comment: great answer, thanks! I have enough data that I need to use `chrome.storage.local`, not `chrome.storage.sync`.