# Saving Chrome Extension Data (with LocalForage)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, localforage

I'm new to web and chrome extension dev and am trying to use the localForage API to store data for my chrome extension- currently I lose everything everytime I switch to a new tab, but I want the data to stay until the user explicitly clears everything out (so even over multiple sessions, etc.)

I decided to give the localForage api a go (since it's supposed to be like localStorage but simpler) and feel like I'm missing something important- I can setItems/getItems without issues but it's not actually saving any of the data.

How exactly do I make sure my data stays while switching tabs (and over multiple browsing sessions)?

Using localForage.getItem/setItem- this seems to be working as far as using the data but isn't doing anything as far as saving it when I switch tabs

```
citeUrl(values, function(citation) 
    {
      count++;
      var string = citation[0];
      localforage.setItem(string, [citation[0],citation[1]], function(err, value) 
      {// Do other things once the value has been saved.
        console.log(value[0] + " " + value[1]);
      });
      /*var result = document.getElementById('cite[]');
      result.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
      result.style.display = 'block';
      result.innerHTML = citation[0];
      renderStatus(citation[1]);*/

      for(i = 0; i < count ; i++)
      {
        var newCitation = document.createElement('div');
        localforage.getItem(citation[i], function(err, value)
          {
            newCitation.innerHTML = value[1] + "<br>" + value[0];
          }
        );
        newCitation.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        newCitation.style.marginBottom = "7px";
        newCitation.style.padding = "6px";
        newCitation.style.boxShadow= "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
        newCitation.style.borderRadius = "3px";
        document.getElementById("answered[]").appendChild(newCitation);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps try https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Answer (score 0):

[`localForage`](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) is built upon `localStorage` and friends. The important part is that it is bound to the origin in which you access it.

Using it from a content script uses the website's origin, e.g. using your extension on `http://example.com/test` will bind the data to `http://example.com/` origin, and using your extension on `http://example2.com/test` will bind the data to a completely independent store attached to origin `http://example2.com/`. What's more, the data is shared with (and may interfere with) the page's own storage.

As such, using `localStorage` (and by extension, `localForage`) does not allow for intended results in a content script (though it may be still useful if you're trying to manupulate the page's own storage).

So, there are 2 possiblities to do it correctly:

1. If you must use it at all, use `localForage` in the background script. In that case, the data is bound to origin `chrome-extension://yourextensionidhere`. However, this is not accessible from content scripts - you'll need to pass data using [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), which is tiresome.
2. Better, extension-specific approach: use native [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), which is shared between all parts of the extension. This API specifically exists to address the need-to-pass-data limitations, among other things.
3. (Win lots of internet points approach) Write a [custom driver for localForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage/wiki/Custom-Drivers) using `chrome.storage` API. This will allow people to use it in Chrome extensions and apps with ease. Which is, apparently, [something already attempted](https://github.com/vikrantpogula/localForage/commit/bdaf0059594bc3e61039726333982b4e6e690503).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279495/window-localstorage-vs-chrome-storage-local/) may be of use.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use the chrome.storage API, but for some reason it's not executing the storage.sync parts (at least on the console) until all the other statements are logged- am I doing something wrong?

'getCurrentTabUrl(function(values) 
    {citeUrl(values,function(citation){
          var keys = ""+citation[0];
          console.log(keys) 
          chrome.storage.sync.set({keys:citation},function()
            {console.log("yay");});
           var m = new Map();
          m.set(1,"black");
          m.forEach(function (item, key, mapObj)
          { console.log(item.toString());});'

Comment: sorry didn't realize it would format it so weirdly. Here's a picture: [link] (http://imgur.com/dtTNzM7)

it will log the 'key is' statement and the map parts before it logs the 'yay'- is this something weird I should just ignore or is it an actual problem with my code?

Comment: `chrome.storage` is asynchronous. The rest of your code executes before the value is saved and the callback is called. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) for instance for more explanation.