# Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Within my *options.html* file, I am setting a value in `chrome.storage.local`, but I can't `get()` the value when I try to, from within my *popup.html*. It's like it can't get it, because it is on a "different" site (the popup site). This is what I get:

```
Error in response to storage.get:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://fcbadpjebgjnohhcihmkopdbnbjjmnod/load_id_to_popup.js:8:37)
    at chrome-extension://fcbadpjebgjnohhcihmkopdbnbjjmnod/load_id_to_popup.js:2:22
```

It's not a typo, right? Please tell me it is, that would be lovely easy to fix.

([First post (solved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038011/extension-chrome-storage-set/41056054#41056054))

**options.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Teamsepak 3 Server Viewer Options</title>
  <style>
    body: { padding: 10px; }
  </style>

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>ENTER YOUR ID FROM tsindex.com BELOW</p>
      <form>
          <input id="ts_id_js_html" type="text" value="128856"></input>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button id="execButton">Save/Load</button>
      </form> 
    <div id="initialize">
      <div id="initialize_id"></div>
      <div id="initialize_if"></div>
      <div id="initialize_else"></div>
    </div>

<script src="initialize_id.js"></script>
<script src="options.js"></script>
<script src="load_id.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**options.js**

```js
//Javascript Document
document.getElementById("execButton").addEventListener("click", store); //adds button functionality to button (id=execButton)

    function store(){
    var input_id = document.getElementById("ts_id_js_html").value;

    chrome.storage.local.set({"ts_id_js": input_id}, function (obj) {
    chrome.storage.local.get("ts_id_js", function (obj) {
        console.log("ts_id_js INSIDE func. test (is this your ID?):" + obj.ts_id_js);
   });

});
}
```

**load_id_to_popup.js** here seems to be the problem, this can't GET the desired value.

```js
//Javascript Document
chrome.storage.local.get("ts_id_js", function (obj) {

if (obj.ts_id_js == undefined || null){
    document.getElementById('input_id').dataset.serverid = 128856;
    console.log("Default ID (128856) loaded to popup.html.");
} else {
    document.getElementById('input_id').dataset.serverid = obj.ts_id_js;
    console.log("Stored ID loaded to popup.html.");
}

});
```

**popup.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ts3index-viewer" id="input_id" data-serverid="128856" data-style="clientc=030B80"><a href="http://ts3index.com/?page=server&id=">TS3index.com</a></div>
    <script src="load_id_to_popup.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "name": "Teamspeak - xxxxx Community",
  "description": "This extension will show Users that are Online on our Teamspeaks Server.",
  "version": "1.4.1",
  "options_page": "options.html",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "ts3.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "storage"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts":["popup.js", "load_id.js", "onclick_button.js", "load_id_to_popup.js", "initialize_id.js", "jquery-2.2.0.min.js", "options.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["popup.js", "load_id.js", "onclick_button.js", "load_id_to_popup.js", "initialize_id.js", "options.js", "jquery-2.2.0.min.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Remove `load_id_to_popup.js` from `background` and `content_scripts" field in `manifest.json`, have a try again.

Comment: @HaibaraAi Thanks for the idea - but that did nothing :( Any other idea?

Comment: First you should know your issue is not how `chrome.storage.get` used but `Cannot read property 'dataset' of null`, that means `document.getElementById('input_id')` is `null`, you should check if the element is retrieved first.

Comment: @HaibaraAi but this `chrome.storage.local.get("ts_id_js", function (obj) {...}` should be getting it, no?
I already set the id beforehand with the options.js. I think I am not grasping something fundamental.

Comment: *Please* do not load jQuery and all of those scripts into `<all_urls>` unless you **have** to. That is a *lot* of code with which to burden *every single page* (what of those of us who have hundreds of tabs open?). It is possible you really *need* to load all of it into every page. However, even if your UI interaction is starting from within the page (one reason to use a *manifest.json* content script), try to architect the extension so only the minimum is loaded until the user begins interaction with your UI, then inject the rest.</all_urls>

Comment: Why are yo using  `document.getElementById` if you are also injecting jQuery into every page?

Comment: @Makyen Do you have a guide source or something for this? I don't really know much about that. It would be totally fine if it only loads when either the Options.html is open or the popup.html. I actually don't want the JS to start on any other site than those of the plugin themselfes.
Maybee you know what I should enter instead of all urls?

Comment: @frizzant: Without knowing what you are attempting to do it is difficult to advise. Part of the issue is having all your code loaded everywhere makes it a more difficult to understand what you are trying to do. From what is in your Question, and your comment, it appears that it might be more effective to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` to inject a content script rather than a *manifest.json* `content_scripts` entry (but what you are doing with any content script is not clear so that may, or may not, be the case). It is also not clear if this is to work on all URLs, or specific URLs.

Answer (score 1):

As Haibara Ai said in comments, the actual error is that `document.getElementById('input_id')` returns `null` meaning the element does not exist.  This happens because you are indiscriminately loading all of your popup scripts as both `background` and `content_scripts` in addition to loading them in your *popup.html*. Thus, you get the error which you reported when the script runs as either a background script (once) or a content script (every page) due to no matching element existing.

In your *manifest.json*, you need to change the scripts defined in the `scripts` key within `background` and the `js` key within `content_scripts`. Without more complete information about your extension it is not possible to determine exactly which scripts should be listed in `background` and which should be loaded in `content_scripts`. However, unless you know that you should load a script into both `background` and `content_scripts`, most will go in only one or the other.

You will want something like the following for the `background` and `content_scripts` entries in your *manifest.json*.  From the `background` and `content_scripts` entries, I have removed the entry for *options.js*, which is clearly for your *options.html*.  I have also removed *load_id_to_popup.js*, which is clearly for your *popup.html*. In addition, I have remove *popup.js*. While you did not include that in your question, it is very likely to be just for your *popup.html*

In the `background` and `content_scripts` I have also commented out *load_id.js* and *initialize_id.js* because they look to be for your *options.html*. You did not include them in the question, so I'm assuming they are not used really used elsewhere.

You have not included *onclick_button.js* in the question, so it is not clear where, if anywhere, it should be referenced in your *manifest.json. However, if it supposed to be in the *manifest.json*, then it probably should only be in one or the other of `background` and `content_scripts`.

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Teamspeak - xxxxx Community",
  "description": "This extension will show Users that are Online on our Teamspeaks Server.",
  "version": "1.4.1",
  "options_page": "options.html",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "ts3.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "storage"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts":[
      "jquery-2.2.0.min.js", //jQuery needs to be loaded prior to where you use it
      //"load_id.js",        //Appears to be for options.html; probably don't want it here
      "onclick_button.js"  //Unknown; Likely use in only one of background/content_scripts
      //"initialize_id.js",  //Appears to be for options.html; probably don't want it here
    ]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        //Try to avoid loading jQuery into <all_urls> unless you really **need** it.
        "jquery-2.2.0.min.js",//jQuery needs to be loaded prior to where you use it
        //"load_id.js",      //Appears to be for options.html; probably don't want it here
        "onclick_button.js"//Unknown;Likely use in only one of background/content_scripts
        //"initialize_id.js",//Appears to be for options.html; probably don't want it here
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In addition, your `manifest_version` should be 2, not 3.

Comment: i don't get where I have to add the scripts, when I should not add them there?

Comment: @frizzant, I have provided more information in the answer about the changes I made to your *manifest.json*. Normally, scripts are only referred to in one place (one of `background`, `content_scripts`, the *popup.html* or *options.html*).  If you are referring to the same script in more than one of those, then something may be wrong. You can use the same script in more than one, but doing so is unusual. You would normally do so if you were sharing some common code, libraries, some global variables. Doing so would normally be a conscious choice.

Comment: @frizzant, I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)  (and perhaps work through reading the pages linked from there). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.