# Angular 2 LocalStorage clears after refresh

Tags: javascript, angular

Little weird little thing here :)

So what I'm doing is when trying to log user in, I want to store access_token and expires in localStorage. Which is working "ok". But If I refresh the page the tokens are gone also if I want to see added tokens after I click login button I need to restart console (F12) in order to see them. Would you be able to see what am I doing wrong?

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AppSettings } from '../AppSettings.component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    private headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    });

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    loginUser(email: string, password: string, remember: boolean) {
        var data = {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'client_id': AppSettings.CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': AppSettings.CLIENT_SECRET,
            'remember': remember
        };
        return this.http.post(AppSettings.HOST + 'auth/login', data, {headers: this.headers})
            .map(
                (response: Response) => {
                    const loginData = response.json().Result;
                    return loginData;
                })
            .do(
                responseData => {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(responseData.access_token));
                    localStorage.setItem('expires', JSON.stringify(responseData.expires));
                }
            );
    }
}
```

And if I refresh the page all tokens are gone too.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.8",
    "angular2-social-login": "^2.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
  }
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'login-layout',
    templateUrl: './app/views/login/login.component.html',
    providers: [ UserService ]
})

export class LoginComponent {
    user: {};
    email: string = '';
    password: string = '';
    remember: boolean;

    constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}

    loginForm() {
        this._userService.loginUser(this.email, this.password, this.remember).subscribe(
            responseData => console.log(responseData),
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    }


}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok checked on Firefox. Tokens are stored correctly even after refresh. Seems like Chrome issue. Anyone else came accross this before?

Comment: The code above seems okay. Can you check if localStorage is being cleared when your page loads/starts from the code somewhere? Are you using incognito mode for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... Found an issue to access localStorage crossbrowser you need to use `localStorage["key"]`

Silly mistake.... :)

More information can be found in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279495/window-localstorage-vs-chrome-storage-local)

Comment: I can only accept this as an answer in 2 days since I was the one that answered it :)