# Chrome storage replacement for NodeJs pure app

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, storage, google-chrome-storage

I have an extension running in Chrome and it uses chrome.storage.local but I want to move it to NodeJS because I need it as a daemon or background task, always running, and Chrome is crashing sometimes.

Do you know if there is some API to avoid a heavy modification?
I found a replacement for Local Storage (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage), but not for Chrome Storage, and they are not the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24281357/420803

I need these features:

- Sutomatically serialize to JSON
- onChange Events
- Allow Default values
- Async

I was thinking maybe in NeDB but is not maintained anymore.

Comment: I would write the entire polyfill or a wrapper for any maintained node.js storage myself, seems both simple and interesting. A polyfill/wrapper means the main code won't have to change.