# Any way to recover local storage data from a deleted Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for Chrome, and by accident I deleted the unpacked extension and reloaded it without making a copy of the data (i.e. data saved in local storage with `chrome.storage.local.set()`). Is my data gone forever?

Comment: That's not Local Storage. Each extension has its own storage: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24279495 If you don't see it in your nested AppData folder, it was probably deleted when the extension was deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is. Part of the process of removing an extension is deleting all its storage footprints.

Comment: Got it. :/ Ok thanks.